# Parse Cloud Code beforeSave not running on update

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have defined a Parse Cloud Code function for beforeSave below.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var publicACL = new Parse.ACL();
  publicACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
  publicACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

  request.object.setACL(publicACL);

  response.success();
});
```

This code runs correctly whenever I save a new Parse.User.  However, when I try to update a pre-existing Parse.User, the code does not execute.  Any thoughts?  Below is the code I am using to update my user.

function updateStudentTypes(id, studentType, chkBox) {

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.get(id, {
  success: function(user) {
    var typeList = user.get("studentType");

    if(!chkBox.checked)
      typeList = removeStudentType(typeList, studentType);
    else
      typeList = addStudentType(typeList, studentType);

    user.set("studentType", typeList);
    user.save(null, {
      success: function(user) {
        //alert('New object created with objectId: ' + user.id);
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert('Failed to update user: ' + error.message);
      }
    }); 

  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    alert("Error querying user: " + error);
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the beginning of your updateStudent method:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Edit: I thought your code was cloud code, not client side javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried this, but it didn't work. My updateUsers method is running on a web page through Javascript, and I get an undefined is not a function error.

Comment: You need to use cloud code to query users. It can't be done client side

Comment: Querying is working on the client side, without issue. I just can't "update" the user objects. Are you saying I need to create Cloud Code to "update" user objects, and then use the useMasterKey() function?

Comment: Sorry may have misspoke. It would all depend on your ACL permissions. Are you trying to change the currentUser's data, or another users data? By default(No ACL set at all) the PFUser ACL permissions are public:read but not public:write

Comment: If you are trying to save another user yes you can still overcome this by creating cloud code to override the ACL's by using the userMasterKey(); function.

Comment: Agreed. I did that, see the code I posted in my original post for the beforeSave function. Now we are back to the original question - the beforeSave isn't firing on User object updates.

Comment: After further investigation I am conforming what you are seeing, it does allow me to set up a user object with write permissions initially, but as you stated not after, even with masterKey permissions.

Comment: Good, glad it is re-createable at least. I am going to try to create a cloud code function for updating the User object and see if that works.